# Use Cheerio to get a variable value inside script tag

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

172/5000
Good afternoon! I am trying to get the value of the variable "var JS_WCACHE_CK =" inside the  tag, but I have already tested and tried to adapt some codes, but without success.

```
<script>
    var JS_IDIOMA = "pt";
    var JS_LINK_ROOT = "https://tabuademares.com";
    var JS_RUTA_ASSETS = "/assets/";
    var CONF_FORMATO_HORA = 1;
    window.google_analytics_uacct = "UA-8166479-17";
    var JS_URL_ACTUAL="%2Fbr%2Fespirito-santo%2Fvitoria";
    var JS_FECHA_ACTUAL="2020-01-26+19%3A00";
    var JS_CODIGO_ESTACION="br56";
    var JS_WCACHE_CK="Mjg5Ng==";
    var JS_ACTIVAR_SERVIDOR_BACKUP=1;
    var JS_LATITUD="-20.32352";
    var JS_LONGITUD="-40.29919";
    var JS_ZOOM="12";   
</script>
```

Link site is: https://tabuademares.com/br/espirito-santo/vitoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say Cheerio is not what you're after. A more appropriate too is [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), as you need something that not only parses the html but also has a language engine so you can interact with on page script without having to do evil things such as `eval`:

```
import { Browser, launch, Page, Response } from "puppeteer";

export class JsVarService {
  private browser!: Browser;
  private page!: Page;

  constructor(private url: string) {}

  public async getVarValue(varName: string): Promise<string> {
    await this.getResponse();
    const results = <string>await this.page.evaluate(`window["${varName}"]`);
    await this.close();
    return results;
  }

  private async getResponse(): Promise<Response | null> {
    this.browser = await launch();
    this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
    return this.page.goto(this.url);
  }

  private async close(): Promise<void> {
    this.browser.disconnect();
  }
}

async function run(): Promise<void> {
  const url = "https://tabuademares.com/br/espirito-santo/vitoria";
  const varName = "JS_WCACHE_CK";
  const service = new JsVarService(url);
  console.log(await service.getVarValue(varName));
}

run().catch(e => { throw new Error(e) });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, except that I know almost nothing about typescript. But I will try to adapt. Anything back here! Thanks!

Comment: Ali Habibzadeh thanks for code! I'm adapt do .js and works!!

Comment: Glad it helped. sorry, haven't written js a long time :)